# embedded webserver for status reporting in c++?

Tags: c++, web-services

I'm writing a large system in C++ and want to include an embedded webserver for management and reporting.  Can anyone make some recommendations?

Comment: you might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175507/c-c-web-server-library. There are a number of suggestions there -- I'd probably have a look at http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/ to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/). It is free, open-source, cross-platform embedded web server written in C. We are using this in a number of projects and are very happy.

Comment: Thanks.  We use boost asio so I'm actually just going with the example httpd in there.